# what is Mysql Database query for this table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table of products sales that may look as follows:

```
product   | value    | ID            
lux       | 6        | 1     
lux       | 76       | 1     
lux       | 3        | 2     
lux       | 474      | 1     
lux       | 474      | 2 
sonu      | 12       | 1
```

what is the mysql code : i want to add all value if the name is same and id is 1 in a new row, also i want to add all value if the name is same and id is 2 in another row
like as

```
product   | sum1| sum2
lux       | 556 | 477  
sonu      | 12  | 0
```

Comment: SELECT P.p_quantity ,Q.p_quantityY FROM 
(
select sum(`p_quantity`) as `p_quantity` from tbl_yarn1 WHERE track=1 group by style_name) P
,
(
select sum(`p_quantity`) as `p_quantityY` from tbl_yarn1 WHERE track=2 group by style_name) Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression in the `sum`:

```
SELECT   product,
         SUM (CASE id WHEN 1 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS sum1,
         SUM (CASE id WHEN 2 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS sum2
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY product
```

Comment: Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: .SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: @MD.AnamulHasan `.SUM`? Are you sure you didn't replace one of the `,`s there with a `,`?